# Boost.python failed with libboost_python.so.1.41.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: boost-python

I have already installed Boost.Python. There were no erros during instalation, but I have a problem. When I try to build my project ererything is OK, but when I run my wrapped project there is an error:

```
import wrraped_project
ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.41.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to copy the project to libboost_python.so.1.41.0 also the lib to the project etc. But every time I have the sme error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the boost library files are in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If that doesn't help, check if the filename is correct, and create a symlink if different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the relevant content of your /usr/lib directory? I'm assuming you're on Linux, right? And did you install Boost.Python with a package manager?

Comment: I have installed the Boost.python on a server without package manager. Actually the problem was in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Thx